# How to run Foreground service after app has been closed

Tags: android

I'm trying to start the Foreground service after the application has been stopped, like in this video https://youtu.be/bOy8xISyAgo, but it doesn't work. I am testing my app on Redmi 10 C (Android 12). When you click on the cross (as in the video), the Foreground service stops.

It is not possible to use BroadcastReceiver on screen off/on due to restrictions added in Android 8.
I also tried to use WorkManager, but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start foreground service if the app is closed. Refer [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions).

Although there are few exemptions as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions). These exemptions are supposed to be use correctly i.e. you should not send high priority notification just to start a foreground service.